# Don't understand how this C++ method works, and want to do something similar

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add another function to a large program I've been working on. It's a 3D game, and a lot of it was built before I got here. If I want to add something, I'll usually look for other places where something similar has been done and make my changes based off that. In this instance however the method I'm trying to learn from is very complex and I don't really know what is going on (and thus don't know what I need to change about it to make it do what I want it to do).

Here is the normal method:

```
    class Action_GoToZone : public Action {
    public:
        Action_GoToZone() {}
        void eval(const Dialog& dialog, State& state) const {
            ZoneParser::getSingleton().load("../media/zones/" + mZoneFilename, false);
            GameState::getSingleton()._changeState("GameMode");
        }

        static Action* Create(const Script2::Parser::List& list) {
            Action_GoToZone* action = new Action_GoToZone();

            if(list.size() != 1)
                throw Translator::TranslateException("GoToZone Action takes exactly one parameter");

            const Script2::Parser::ListElement& e1 = list.front();
            if(!e1.mIsIdentifier)
                throw Translator::TranslateException("GoToZone Action only takes identifiers");

            action->mZoneFilename = String(e1.mIdentifier.mString);
            action->mReturnFilename = ZoneParser::getSingleton().getLastFilename();

            return action;
        }

    private:
        String mZoneFilename;
        String mReturnFilename;
    };
```

All I want my method to do is to call a function within a different class. Here is what I attempted:

```
class Action_SetJob : public Action {
    public:
        Action_SetJob() {}
        void eval(const Dialog& dialog, State& state) const {
            GameModeState::changeJob(1); //This is the class/function I want it to call.
        }

        static Action* Create(const Script2::Parser::List& list) {
            Action_SetJob* action = new Action_SetJob();

            if(list.size() != 1)
                throw Translator::TranslateException("SetJob Action takes exactly one parameter");

            const Script2::Parser::ListElement& e1 = list.front();
            if(!e1.mIsIdentifier)
                throw Translator::TranslateException("SetJob Action only takes identifiers");

            action->GameModeState::changeJob(1);

            return action;
    private:
        int changeJob;
        }   
    };
```

I don't really know what action-> is for... I tried it with taking out `action->GameModeState::changeJob(1);` and all content below that but that threw up errors.

This probably isn't enough information to solve the problem, but I'd be happy with any explanation about the method, if you can.

Comment: You do realize all people have to do to see the code is to click on the "edited x seconds ago" link, right?...

Comment: It's better than nothing

Comment: -1 Removing the question is pretty self-serving in my opinion and not what this site is intended for.

Comment: @Bart Sorry you feel that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, then this should accomplish it:

```
class Action_SetJob : public Action {
public:
    Action_SetJob() {}
    void eval(const Dialog& dialog, State& state) const {
        GameModeState::changeJob(newJob);
    }

    static Action* Create(const Script2::Parser::List& list) {
        Action_SetJob* action = new Action_SetJob();

        if(list.size() != 1)
            throw Translator::TranslateException("SetJob Action takes exactly one parameter");

        const Script2::Parser::ListElement& e1 = list.front();
        if(!e1.mIsInteger)
            throw Translator::TranslateException("SetJob Action only takes integers");

        action->newJob = e1.mInteger.mInt;

        return action;
    }   
private:
    int newJob;
};
```

Obviously since C++ is context-sensitive (it's actually an undecidable language), I cannot know what other members your classes have so I guessed what could be likely.

You want to parse an integer that you can pass to the function you are trying to call when the action gets evaluated.

This is assuming your changeJob method is static. If it is not actually static, you will have to somehow figure out the target object; you can do that by adding an other parameter to your script function for example.

If you want more details, we need more information!

Comment: Thank you for your help! This has helped me a little in pushing forward to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

`->`  is a pointer reference.  It looks like your objects are pointers (from the `*` after the object type).  Is the problem with the pointer operations or with something else? From what you wrote, I'm not exactly sure what entirely to offer help with aside from your mention of `action->`